# Selenium / Beautiful Soup / AutoItScript automation

Tags: python, selenium, beautifulsoup, autoit

I'm trying to automate a login to http://www.eedistribution.com/.
I have tried this for IE:

```
driver = webdriver.Ie("D:\\Python\\IEDriverServer32.exe")
driver.get("http://www.entertainmentearth.com/eedistribution.asp")
inputName = driver.find_element_by_name("custnum").send_keys("user")
passWord = driver.find_element_by_name("password").send_keys("password")
submit = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//input[@type='image']").click()`
```

and this for firefox:

```
driver = webdriver.Firefox()
driver.get("http://www.eedistribution.com/")
inputName = driver.find_element_by_name("custnum").send_keys("user")
passWord = driver.find_element_by_name("password").send_keys("password")
submit = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//input[@type='image']").click()
```

The website has two sides. Wholesale distribution and consumer.  For some reason when I use the above scripts it takes me to the consumer side when I want to go to the wholesale side. If I manually enter user / password then I get into the wholesale side.

Also If I use AutoITscript:

```
oIE = _IEAttach("ee")

$user = _IEGetObjByName($oIE, "custnum")

$login = _IEGetObjByName($oIE, "password")

$oInputs = _IETagNameGetCollection($oIE, "input")

$user.value = "user"

$login.value = "password"

For $oInput in $oInputs

   If StringInStr($oInput.outerhtml, "signin_white.gif") > 0 Then

      $oInput.click()

      ExitLoop

   EndIf

Next
```

It works fine. I can't figure out why one script would do this and the other wouldn't. Any suggestions?

Thanks,

Mike

Answer (score 0):

Someone else helped me in another board. There were two separate buttons and i was grabbing the wrong one.